# How to enable code recommenders for eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I click "Enable intelligent call completion" from the preferences but it still does not recommend.  Anything else that needs to be done?  And when I look at all the jars, there doesn't seem to be any recommendation models associated to any of the jars, it says Resolution Status UNRESOLVED for all.  I tried using a few different SDKs, 1.6 and 1.7. Is it because I'm behind a proxy? Receiving updates to eclipse works so I do not think that's the issue.

Comment: Have you tried restarting eclipse? Restarting your computer?

Answer (score 4):

[Not all libraries are supported yet](http://www.eclipse.org/recommenders/documentation/usr.html).

> At the time of writing this section (1.0.0.rc2), Code Recommenders partially supports the Java Standard Library, namely the main packages under java.* and some packages under javax.* . As the recommendation models are generated from the Eclipse Juno Release Train code base only, packages like java.awt or javax.swing are not supported as no data was available at generation time. For a detailed list of which libraries or packages are supported, check the reports section on the Code Recommenders home page.

I also see all my Android libraries, Apache commons, Google commons and so on not being resolved.

Besides that resolution issue, you surely know that you can cycle through all available suggestions using Ctrl-Space multiple times, or that you can reorder the list of suggestions in Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Content Assist -> Advanced (once you got your libraries resolved).

Answer (score 1):

How does your .metdata/.plugins/.org.eclipse.recommenders.rcp folder look like?
Do you use a proxy to connect to the internet?

There is a fix available. See http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/366941/ for more details.